# Flask-OAuthlib get access_token from token handler

Tags: python, oauth, flask, oauth-2.0

I need to return custom user fields on successful access_token request from @oauth.token_handler. I see this can be done if I return some json data like this example from the [docs](http://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#token-handler)

```
@app.route('/oauth/token')
@oauth.token_handler
def access_token():
    return {'version': '0.1.0'}
```

But how can I access the user information from the original request or the obtained access_token in here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that because `@oauth.token_handler` is outside the scope of the current request.

I solved by providing a `/me` endpoint which provides the current logged user's info: `request.oauth.user`.